# Getting Array from Prompt and Inserting into MongoDB Database

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I am working on a social network type site. I am wanting a way in which I can prompt users, get their response in an array, and then insert the array all at once. Whilst I can prompt I'm having trouble inserting the array into the mongodb database. Here is my code:

```
'click #creator': function(event){

  var channelName = prompt('Enter The Channel Name');
  var howmany = +prompt('How many people do you want? (max 10)');  
  var users = [];  
  var arr = [];  // define our array

  if(howmany > 1 && howmany<10){
    for (var i = 0; i < howmany; i++) {              // loop 10 times
      arr.push(prompt('Enter a user' + (i+1))); // push the value into the array
    }

    users = arr.join('"," ');     
    Meteor.call('addChannel', channelName, users);
  }
}
```

Inserting it in:

```
 Channels = new Mongo.Collection('channels');
 Meteor.methods({
   addChannel: function(channelName, users){
     if(!Meteor.userId()) {
       throw new Meteor.Error('not-authorized', 'you are not signed in');
     }

     var username = Meteor.user().username;

     Channels.insert({
       name: channelName,
       created: new Date(), 
       members: $push: {users} 
       createdBy: username
     });
   },
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are inserting and `users` is already an array you don't need to `$push`. Plus you don't need to push an `{}` object.

```
Channels.insert({
  name: channelName,
  created: new Date(), 
  members: users, 
  createdBy: username
});
```

Meanwhile on the client side, skip the `arr.join()` - that is creating a string but you just want to pass the array you created directly.

```
Meteor.call('addChannel', channelName, arr);
```

Comment: That worked perfectly!! And you're gonna get an upvote and correct answer. But I'm now having one slight problem. When a new user joins, they get put in a community channel. Whilst all created channels show, and only show to those in it the community channel is no longer showing in the channels bar. Although it does connect the user to the community channel, but I still want it to show up so they could change to it if they wanted to.

Comment: I use this to display it:     channels: function () {
     var username = Meteor.user().username;
        return Channels.find({$or: [
            {members: username},
            {createdBy: username},
            {name: 'Community'}
        ]});
        
    }

Comment: `{members: {$in: username}}` even though that looks backwards. The `$in` operator can be used symmetrically.